# Python memory address

Tags: python-3.x, memory

i have noticed that when operation are performed, the memory address changes

```
a = 3
print(id(a))

a += 1
print(id(a))
```

1467903104
1467903136

however when we use the built-in

```
a.__add__(1)
```

the address remains the same. 
Any idea why this is so?

Comment: Because you never assign the result of `a.__add__(1)` back to `a`, so the object at `a` never changes. IOW, `a += 1` is essentially equivalent to `a = a.__add__(1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comment:

> Because you never assign the result of `a.__add__(1)` back to `a`, so the object at a never changes. IOW, `a += 1` is essentially equivalent to `a = a.__add__(1)`